# Can anyone help to parse HCL?

Tags: go, hcl

I'm going to parse HCL configuration file using [this repository](https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    hclParser "github.com/hashicorp/hcl/hcl/parser"
)

const (
    EXAMPLE_CONFIG_STRING = "log_dir = \"/var/log\""
)

func main() {
    // parse HCL configuration
    if astFile, err := hclParser.Parse([]byte(EXAMPLE_CONFIG_STRING)); err == nil {
        fmt.Println(astFile)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Parsing failed.")
    }
}
```

How can I parse `log_dir` in this case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

github.com/hashicorp/hcl/hcl/parser is a low-level package. Use the [high-level API](https://godoc.org/github.com/hashicorp/hcl#Decode) instead:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"

        "github.com/hashicorp/hcl"
)

type T struct {
        LogDir string `hcl:"log_dir"`
}

func main() {
        var t T
        err := hcl.Decode(&t, `log_dir = "/var/log"`)
        fmt.Println(t.LogDir, err)
}
```

There is also DecodeObject available if you really want to deal with the AST yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's helpful much to me.